# Network Traffic flow

Tags: networking, traffic, copying

Let's say I copy a network folder(Machine A) contents to another(Machine B) and I do this copying operation on a different machine (Machine C). How does the traffic flow? Does the data flow from Machine A to Machine B directly? or does it go through Machine C?

Edit:- Seems like different protocols work differently. I'm interested in whatever protocol that works behind Windows Network copy

Comment: This is protocol dependent. Can you clarify how you are copying the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With windows shares (cifs / smb ), like most protocols, all the trafic will go through the C computer. You can verify it with performance monitor.

Comment: ...or see the traffic with Wireshark. Removes all doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you use.  FTP can do do it so the traffic never goes through machine C, it is called [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol).

Comment: Most ftp servers won't let you do this anymore though, or prevent ftp bouncing.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are operating at C, there is no other way then data to come from A to C then from C to B.  So, you are wasting twice the network resources you need.

However, if you use Remote Desktop to login to B and pull data directly from A, you'll manage to go lot cheaper, since data will flow directly, and only other overhead will be remote console updates.  Even more, use telnet and log into B to pull data from A via the command line.

Hope that clarifies it.